# mysql SUM not giving correct value

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have a SUM query that isnt returning the correct value.
It returns 1, not the value

There are 2 entries in the table both have the `amount` column value 200
so the SUM should return 400 .. not 1

My query is below

Thanks

```
$owtbdq = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `crm`.`workshop-otherwork` WHERE `wsjid` = '$wsjid'");
        $owtbdr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($owtbdq);
        $owtbdc = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT SUM(amount) FROM `crm`.`workshop-otherwork` WHERE `wsjid` = '$wsjid'");
        $owtbdcount = mysqli_fetch_assoc($owtbdc);
```

I have also tried it without the ` around amount and same result

I have just ran

```
 SELECT SUM(amount) FROM `crm`.`workshop-otherwork` WHERE `wsjid` = '4'
```

in HeidiSQL and it correctly returned 400 so havent a clue

Comment: SELECT SUM(amount) FROM crm.workshop-otherwork WHERE wsjid = $wsjid. Run this drectly on phpmyadmin and see the result

Comment: And this is why meaningful variables names should be used.

Comment: the names are meaningful to me
$owtbd = other work to be done
$wtbd = work to be done

Just because you don't know what they mean doesnt mean myself or anyone else in our company doesnt

Comment: you went and overwrote your original question without making it as an additional edit.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  i actually put NEW CODE above the code I just put 
All I have pasted shows exactly what I am trying to do

Comment: @ChrisYates Your code changes invalidate all the answers.  The is a no no.  If you have different code you should ask a new question with that new code.

Comment: didnt know that apologies , have returned code to original, have just added a new line showing the new mysqli_fetch_assoc statement

Comment: @ChrisYates I feel that we don't have all of the parts for this and how you're trying to echo that out. You were originally trying to reference the wrong query. What is the db schema for this and are those columns int's or varchars? You can't do math on varchar. You might even have to add an alias to the sum query. I.e.: `SELECT SUM(amount) as the_count`.

Comment: the column datatype is decimal

Answer (score 2):

You should fetch the second request ($owtbd**c**)

```
$owtbdr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($owtbdc);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have written `$owtbdq` in `mysqli_fetch_assoc($owtbdq);` where you are not doing SUM. you should do like this

`mysqli_fetch_assoc($owtbdc);`

```
$owtbdq = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `crm`.`workshop-otherwork` WHERE `wsjid` = '$wsjid'");
$owtbdc = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT SUM(`amount`) FROM `crm`.`workshop-otherwork` WHERE `wsjid` = '$wsjid'");
$owtbdr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($owtbdq);
```

Comment: $owtbdr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($owtbdq);  is the query result where Im NOT doing the SUM

Comment: What is the datatype of amount column?

Comment: Yes but you are using `$owtbdq` this variable in `mysqli_fetch_assoc($owtbdq)`. you should use `$owtbdc` instead

Comment: nope still nothing

Answer (score 0):

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($owtbdc)
$value = $row[0]
```

I guess this would work.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it

it was finally being returned as an array so did
$newtotal = array_sum($owtbdcount)

that worked

thanks for help guys

Comment: Great but did you have any related code that you should have posted in the first place? Where did `array_sum()` suddenly came about? Were you using another function?

Comment: nope all the code is there ..
dunno just tried it and it worked

Comment: I still think adding an alias to the query would have (also) worked. You should try it and see ;-)

Comment: not sure i understand, can you post what you'd like me to try ?

Comment: [I already did...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44632096/mysql-sum-not-giving-correct-value#comment76252441_44632096) ;-) the alias would then be used in the echo'd row's reference.

Comment: yep that works too

Comment: Just like I said ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Print a `var_dump()`, I guess you are getting a resource link. 
Your query is correct, not your PHP code.

EDIT: sorry, it returns an identifier -> http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc

```
$owtbdc = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT SUM(amount) FROM `crm`.`workshop-otherwork` WHERE `wsjid` = '$wsjid'");

if ($owtbdcount = mysqli_fetch_array($owtbdc)) {
    echo $owtbdcount[0];
}
```

Comment: nothing at all displayed from var_dump